# jQuery: click event not always firing

Tags: jquery, events, click

I use this library to get a searchable dropdown element: https://github.com/opusonline/dropdown

I made a few minor changes (add possibility to add new elements to list)

It generally works fine, but when you really stresstest it (make many selections in a row, scroll alot, hover fast over elements and click right at the top and bottom of the elements in the list), it doesn't select the proper element.

After debugging a little, I came to the conclusion that in these particular cases the click event on the dropdown elements is not fired at all, but the hover events seem to work fine.

And these two are bound to the elements in the same method-chaining, so both should be attached.

Please look at the code at http://jsbin.com/adiyen/1

Any suggestions on further debugging or errors in the code would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the speed to show the popup. Currently you have set it to `speed: 250` and most likely you are performing the selection faster than the animation process is being completed.

Try chaning to a value that you can trade off the animation and the speed of your selection. You might consider `speed: 100` that can give you some acceptable animation and super fast selection of the item in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried speed: 100 and the problems did happen again. To give you an idea what I mean, here is a video with speed: 10 and the problems happening: http://fkiss.info/~felix/dropdown-errors.m4v note what happens at 00:12, 00:42, 00:45, 01:23, 01:31